# Chewy RSpec Test - Expected index `client#person_client` to be updated, but it was not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, elasticsearch

I am using Chewy to interacting with ElasticSearch in a Rails App. I am trying add a RSpec test to my index (ClientIndex), but I think I am doing something wrong here.

My model `Client`:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  update_index('client#person_client') { self }
end
```

My `ClientIndex`:

```
class ClientIndex < Chewy::Index
  settings analysis: {
   # ...
  }

  define_type Client, name: 'person_client' do
    field :id, value: ->(client) { client.id }
    field :name, search_analyzer: 'str_search_analyzer', index_analyzer: 'index_analyzer'

    field :name_sorted, value: ->(client) { client.name }
    field :email, search_analyzer: 'str_search_analyzer', index_analyzer: 'index_analyzer'

    field :created_at, type: 'date'
  end
end
```

And my RSpec test:

```
RSpec.describe ClientIndex do
  it "update index after save" do
    client = Fabricate.build(:client, id: 10)
    expect { client.save! }.to update_index('client#person_client')
  end
end
```

Result:

```
Failures:

  1) ClientIndex update index after save
     Failure/Error: expect { client.save! }.to update_index('client#person_client')
       Expected index `client#person_client` to be updated, but it was not
```

Any suggestions here?

Thanks

Comment: Which chewy version are you using? 0.6.2 or 0.7.0?

Comment: @cbliard with version 0.6.2 works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. In the `spec_helper.rb`, I had to choose the indexation strategy of chewy. I put:

```
Chewy.root_strategy = :urgent
```

and it works now.

If you don't chose the indexation strategy, it raises an error in the callback, but it's silent when you create on object.

I hope this helps.